# I'm not able to use "await" unless it's not in an lambda function

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I've been trying to make a function run asynchronously to prevent the window from freezing everytime it pings a new address but when I tried to implement it, VS said that I can't use the await operator as it's current state. Any suggestions?

```
public MainWindow()
{
    //var reader = new Mp3FileReader(@"Resources\Audio\02 Connecting.flac");
    MediaFoundationReader sound = new MediaFoundationReader(@"Resources\Audio\Connecting.mp3");
    var waveOut = new WaveOut(); // or WaveOutEvent()
    waveOut.Init(sound);
    waveOut.Play();

    InitializeComponent();
    ContentRendered += (s, e) => { await Connecting(); };
}

private async Task Connecting()
{
    AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("23.185.0.1");
    var pingSender = new Ping();

    pingSender.PingCompleted += PingCompletedCallback;
    pingSender.SendAsync(ip, 1000, waiter);
}
```

Comment: Firstly, specify full signature of the first method. Secondly, specify full VS message.

Comment: `ContentRendered += async (s, e) => { await Connecting(); };`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're trying to use [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) in a synchronous delegate:

```
ContentRendered += (s, e) => { await Connecting(); };
```

To use the `await` keyword, you'll need an asynchronous delegate defined, to then add it to the event.

This should work - note the `async` keyword which enables the use of the `await` keyword:

```
ContentRendered += async (s, e) => { await Connecting(); };
```

---

You should also await the asynchronous `pingSender.SendAsync` method:

```
await pingSender.SendAsync(ip, 1000, waiter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are using the `Connecting` asynchronous method in more than one places, it is probably preferable from a maintainability point of view to attach a classic event handler to the `ContentRendered` event:

```
ContentRendered += ContentRenderedHandler;

//...

private async void ContentRenderedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("23.185.0.1");
    var pingSender = new Ping();
    PingReply pingReply = await pingSender.SendPingAsync(ip, 1000);
    // Use the `pingReply` here
}
```

This is essentially the same with what Ermiya Eskandary suggests in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69590468/11178549), with the only difference being that the presence on an [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) method is visible and explicit. The use of `async void` here is correct, because the method is an event handler. It's a good idea to be explicit though, because `async void` methods are too often misused, resulting in unexpected behavior, or compiler warnings, or both.

---

**Update:** Your code makes use of the anachronistic `PingCompleted` + `SendAsync` approach. The [`Ping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping) class offers the newer [`SendPingAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendpingasync) API (.NET Framework 4.5 and later), that can be consumed directly with async-await.